# Typescript infer key names for returned object from function input argument

Tags: typescript

For my react hook I'd like to be able to dictate the name of the returned objects keys for easier destructuring.

```
const [users, { append }] = useList(initialUsers)
const [admins, { append }] = useList(initialAdmins)
```

This wouldn't work of course, since `append` would be defined twice.

One solution would be to rename (one or both of) the returned object keys during the destructing.

However I would like to implement it like this:

```
const [users, { appendUsers }] = useList(initialUsers, "Users")
const [admins, { appendAdmins }] = useList(initialAdmins, "Admins")
```

For that I created this TS function signature:

```
function useList<L extends any>({ initial = [], name = "" }: Options<L> = {}): [ L[], any ] {
   // ...
  return [
    items,
    {
      ["append" + name]: (newItem:L) => set([...items, newItem]),
    },
  ]
}
```

This works, but the returned object keys are not type checked.

I'd like to define the signature of each returned key in the object, and the signature of its value.
At the very least, the number of returned keys should be defined.

Without the dynamic part, that comes via function argument the return signature could be changed to:

```
[ L[], {
  append: ((T) => void)
} ]
```

But I'd need something like:

```
[ L[], {
  ["append" +  name]: ((T) => void)
} ]
```

Comment: You can't  do string manipulation in the type system. It is a requested feature, just not in there right now

Comment: Yeah, [microsoft/TypeScript#12754](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) is where this is being tracked, I think

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to the GH discussion. I have added my posting and and ideas there, but it does not seem to be considered in the near future.